# vmshell failed: Error starting crostini for terminal: 4

Tags: chrome-book, chrome-os

I'm using Google Pixelbook w/ Google Chrome `Version 88.0.4314.0 (Official Build) dev (64-bit)`, when I try to start Terminal (Linux) I get following:

```
[==       ] Checking the virtual machine image Error starting penguin container: 4
Launching vmshell failed: Error starting crostini for terminal: 4
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Go to crosh and type vmc stop termina. That's it. Restart the linux shell and it should work now.

Example: https://youtu.be/yJ8sP7W2XFw